# Where are TFS 2015 custom build tasks stored?

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task

We use TFS 2015 on premise. Where are the TFS 2015 custom build tasks stored? or how can I download a existing build task?

I know you can download the build tasks from github. But this is not what I am looking for.

[image: click here for image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're stored internally in the database. The easiest way to "extract them" is to install a local agent, create a build definition that targets that agent and add the task you want.

Queue the build and the agent will download the task and will store them in a subfolder under the Agent's working directory called "Tasks". Grab the contents from there.

[image]

You'll be able to push the task using the `tfx build tasks upload` command.

If you're downloading tasks from VSTS for installation to a onpremise TFS server, you may need to get access to a specific task version, as the service may be ahead and may have other dependencies which have not been deployed to the TFS server.

Another thing to note is that when downloading a task from VSTS, it may have the preview flag set to true in it's `task.json`, these tasks can be uploaded, but will be invisible in TFS, before uploading them you should remove the reference to `"preview": true` from the `task.json` completely.

Comment: I suppose there is a way to use the API to fetch the download Url for the package, since the build agent is able to download the tasks, but I've found it quite useful to have the agent do the work for me.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as an answer using the check mark in front of the question.